# Fast SQL queries on ranges

Tags: sql, range

I have a table of IP Ranges and their respective city and country that owns that IP Range. The IPs are represented as `bigint` (See equation below for turning IP into `bigint`) and I am doing a select to pull back what cities/countries that are using a website.

Equation for converting IP to number is

```
Bigint = (octet1 * (2^24)) + (octet2 * (2^16)) + (octet3 * (2^8)) + Octet 4
```

My selects are looking like the following below. In either case, when I have a lot of IP addresses (200) to look up, the where clause can get very long and the results take minutes to return. I do have the `startipnum` and `endipnum` indexed as a clustered index. The table has 6.25 million rows of data (IP ranges and countries in it). Is there a better way to return the data?

```
SELECT [startIpNum] ,[endIpNum],[country],[region],[city],[postal_code]
              ,[latitude],[longitude],[metroCode],[areacode] 
FROM [GeoLocationView] 
WHERE
    (30072067 between startipNum and endipnum) 
    OR
    (30072069 between startipNum and endipnum)
```

Or

```
SELECT [startIpNum] ,[endIpNum],[country],[region],[city],[postal_code]
              ,[latitude],[longitude],[metroCode],[areacode] 
FROM [GeoLocationView] 
WHERE
     (startipNum <= 30072067 and 30072067 <= endipnum) or 
     (startipNum <= 30072069 and 30072069 <= endipnum)
```

Comment: What **database** and **version**?? SQL is just the structured query language - **not** a database product ... and stuff like this (perf tuning) is often very much vendor-specific - not a "general purpose" SQL topic, really

Comment: Just a thought, have you considered partitioning the data to prevent hitting all >6mill rows each time?

Comment: @marc_s: given the weird (non-standard) "quoting" style of the question this is very likely SQL Server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, that's my assumption, too - but I'd like to have it confirmed

Comment: The SQL server is a standard Microsoft 2008 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be interesting to try using a table variable (or temp table) with the list of IPs, joined to your lookup table

```
declare @ips table (ip bigint)

insert @ips (ip) values (30072067) -- etc...

SELECT <field list>
  FROM [GeoLocationView]
    inner join @ips as ips
      on ((GeoLocationView.startipNum <= ip) and (GeoLocationView.endipnum) >= ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cluster will help.

I would select `x > ? order by x`

the where clause could be a subselect from a separate table like this:

```
where key exists(select * from key_table)
```

but you have to maintain this key_table ...

When it tries to optimize your query - table lookups serve the RDMS engine better, than a tail of keys

Answer (score 0):

When you have to match a lot of values, an OR clause is often slower than a JOIN on a temporary table.